# Adding a custom css file to a Facebook "Activity Feed"

Tags: facebook, api

I would like to know if there is a way to add a custom css file to an activity feed (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/activity).

Ive tried adding a css="url.to.css" property, but it didnt work. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this way:

```
<fb:tag name='link'>
<fb:tag-attribute name='rel'>stylesheet</fb:tag-attribute>
<fb:tag-attribute name='href'>YOUR_FACEBOOK_CANVAS_PAGE/style.css</fb:tag-attribute>
<fb:tag-attribute name='type'>text/css</fb:tag-attribute>
<fb:tag-attribute name='media'>all</fb:tag-attribute>
</fb:tag>
```

It will be added to your page. Don't forget to edit URL.

Answer (score -1):

I managed to customise an Activity plugin, after a great deal of effort.

You can see the result here:

http://www.quniverse.co.uk/shopdata/about_us.php

Feel free to post a comment on that site, it exists purely for test purposes so I'm not fussed what goes up there provided its clean. Plus if you like the page it will show up as activity. Please don't feel obliged to though.

I explain how I achieved this in the blog article posted here:

http://facebookanswers.co.uk/?p=302

To summarise briefly:

1. You cannot insert CSS into the activity plugin.
2. Rely on the fact it has a transparent background, and supply your own.
3. Turn off the header and supply your own.
4. You can specify a light or a dark font, a few fontfaces and a border colour, when you create the plugin.

If you read the blog article you will get a full explanation.