# Custom Activity Feed for Facebook Page

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

### Research and Reasoning

I haven't worked on a Facebook Application for a while, thus am a little rusty with how the Graph API works.

I have had a look at various topics and pages such as:

1. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/activity/
2. [How to Style Facebook Activity Feed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8745425/how-to-style-facebook-activity-feed)

From what I can gather, getting the activity of a facebook page is pretty simple, however, before I proceed, there are a few things I would like to iron out before to ensure I build the app or write the script in the best possible way...

### My Question

I would like to gather the status updates of a Facebook Like page and then feed this data to my News page on the website I am building.

My method would be a simple call to the Graph API to gather the data, and then display it on screen.

My question is, can I do this without creating a Facebook App, and therefore do I even need the PHP SDK?

Is it possible to achieve it like so and are there any request limits:

```
$url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/LIKE_PAGE_ID/feed';
$result = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));
```

***If the above is the correct answer to this question then please let me know and I will close this question***

### Update

I have tried the above URL with my like page and it says that I need an Access Token. This is what I feared... Is it possible to get this data without being logged in, and without having set up a Facebook Application?

Answer (score 1):

Why not create a Facebook app and use App Access Token to retrieve the feed for the Public pages.

Though you might get `feed` of some pages without app access token or response for different end points without `access_token`, but as the Facebook's API is constantly changing, and would finally settle with authorized request to their end points, I would suggest you to use the [App Access Token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/) which is can be created with the format

```
App_ID|App_Secret
```

So instead of your call for `$url` that you had you can change it to

```
$url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/LIKE_PAGE_ID/feed?access_token=App_ID|App_Secret';
```

Which you can then `json_decode`. Also there is nothing on binding to use PHP SDK, and in your case, it is not even required.